# Using where/select in a query containing Include, when either where/select is not present in the context? Does Where on related table require Include?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0

I have 3 tables:

Contract, matter and claims. Each table has a 1:N relationship with the following table.

I want to select claim name where contract con_name = 'C109K'

```
        var claims = await _context.Claims.AsNoTracking()                            
                        .Include(cl=>cl.Matter)
                        .ThenInclude(mat=>mat.Contract)
                        .Where(con=>con.con_name=='C109K')
                        .Select(cl=>new{name=cl.cl_name})
```

The error is that the where clause is unable to find con_name because the context is claims.

I also tried the other way round - that is - starting the query from contract. But in that case the select is unable to get claim name since the query context is contract.

How can I correctly write this query?

Comment: If I try that I get error that `Contract does not contain a definition for 'Where' and no extension method 'Where'....`. I think that other question has got the relationship other way around, maybe?

Comment: Not seeing the class model makes this hard to answer. Also, do you want to filter `Claims` or the included `Contracts`?

Comment: Filter contract, and select claim name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's hard to be sure without the model, but I assume this should work:

```cs
var claims = await _context.Claims.AsNoTracking()                            
    .Include(cl=>cl.Matter)
    .ThenInclude(mat=>mat.Contract)
    .Where(cl=>cl.Matter.Contract.con_name=='C109K') // <-- find the contract associated with the claim
    .Select(cl=>new{name=cl.cl_name})
```

The `.Include()` and `.ThenInclude()` methods are used to load the related entities (see the documentation on [eager loading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/eager)). They ask EF Core to retrieve the data from the database, and load it in the associated entities.

For example in your case:

```cs
var claim = (await _context.Claims.AsNoTracking()).First();
var matter = claim.Matter; // matter will always be null, because it was no loaded

claim = (await _context.Claims.Include(cl=>cl.Matter).AsNoTracking()).First();
matter = claim.Matter; // the claim's matter is loaded thanks to the Include call
var contract = matter.Contract; // contract is null because it was not loaded

claim = (await _context.Claims.Include(cl=>cl.Matter).ThenInclude(mat=>mat.Contract).AsNoTracking()).First();
matter = claim.Matter; // the claim's matter is loaded thanks to the Include call
contract = matter.Contract; // contract is loaded thanks to the ThenInclude call
```

Those methods allow for granular control over which data is retrieved from your database: sometime you don't need all data, only the top level view.

In your case however, those calls are not needed because you don't retrieve the linked entities: you only need them for filtering, and the filtering is done solely by running the appropriate SQL query.

Comment: Please can you tell me what is the purpose of writing the `.Include` and `.ThenInclude` in this query? As the code works even if I remove them. Can you tell me please.

Comment: They are not needed here. But some people put them everywhere. After `Select` Includes are ignored.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv - please if you could point me to an article that helps me understand how to think in terms of this query language then it will really be helpful (note: I know SQL syntax very well, just need to get my head around this linq syntax)

Comment: If you know SQL. look closer to LINQ Query syntax, I prefer query syntax when I have `SelectMany`, `Join`, `GroupJoin` or `GroupBy` in query. I have learned LINQ while developing LINQ Provider - it is years of experience and my source was internet and right search questions. `Include` is needed only when you want to instruct EF Core to `LOAD` related entities and only for this purpose, not filtering not joining, just instruction to load related data. If you have `Select` at the end - you instruct again which fields  to `LOAD` but more precisely, so EF just ignores `Include`.

Comment: @variable I've added a short explanation of `Include` and `ThenInclude`, with a link to the related documentation.

Comment: You have mentioned that `you only need them for filtering.`, but even if I do remove them, then the filtering works. So are they optional?

Comment: In your case, yes.

Comment: By `you don't retrieve them`- do you mean to say that since I don't retrieve columns from them in the SELECT?

Comment: No, I mean you don't retrieve the _entire entity_. Using them in the select will not require them either. I strongly suggest reading the documentation.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv - So the `include` actually means an internal SQL SELECT prior to the final SELECT?

Comment: @variable, `Include` means only that you want to load related data. How it is implemented by EF Core and which SQL to generate - decision of EF Core developers.